# Spring Cloud - Binding Services Together

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

How do I actually bind REST services together using Spring Cloud?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.  For instance, say that I have 2 separate microservices that are both set up to run with Spring Cloud and Spring Boot.  How do I bind it together so it can have the 1st service call the 2nd one?

My understanding is that Eureka can be used as a service registry.  If we were to use Eureka, what would the code look like to have 1 service call another?

Comment: Eureka is just proxy for the services, now instead of calling your service URL you'll be calling `eureka-url/service-name` URL. There's nothing like cloudfoundry `bind-service` for micro services that we implement. Instead we have to write our own client code. For example you can use `RestTemplat` or `Apache HttpClient` or plain `URLConnection` code for that.

Comment: Everything what you need to know for basics is in their docs, this is really good basic article: https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think other answers are on the right track, but here are some more specifics.

When you use Spring Cloud Netflix to create a Eureka server and clients you can use the [`EurekaClient`](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_using_the_eurekaclient) bean to get the homepage URL of their clients.  You could then use a `RestClient` to call APIs for that client.

You other option, as mentioned above, is to use a [Feign client](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Cloud Netflix](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/) which comes with excellent pattern with  Service Discovery (Eureka), Circuit Breaker (Hystrix), Intelligent Routing (Zuul) and Client Side Load Balancing (Ribbon) will be suitable for large scale distributed systems which is especially built on Micro services.

Also, refer their [good documentation resource](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_netflix).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a API gateway in which you can invoke services from Microservices using FeignClient . Eg Microservice A and Microservice B . In gateway have Feign clients for both the microservices. Write a service in Gateway which will invoke service in A and service in B

Another work around is you can have a ResourceProcessor in Microservice A and FeignClient to MicroService B . Call the service of Microservice B from the Resource Processor of A